# React Day Picker, avoid adding modifier styles for outside days of month

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using [react-day-picker](http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/styling) and in here the custom modifier styles are added to outside days of month.

[image]

How can I avoid adding those styles to dates which is disabled and outside of the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict your CSS selector with `:not('.DayPicker-Day--outside')`, for example:

```
.DayPicker-Day.DayPicker-Day--thursdays:not('.DayPicker-Day--outside') {
  background: yellow;
}
```